# A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'. > A problem occurred configuring project ':app'

Tags: build.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\usama\AndroidStudioProjects\cad_for_Thorax_Diseases\android\build.gradle' line: 27
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\usama\AndroidStudioProjects\cad_for_Thorax_Diseases\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\usama.gradle\caches\7.4\scripts\2ac95qxjpwyc3xsg4ybacjiw2).
> > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 64

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

there show a problem in line 27 but everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

I find the same issue on macOS.

If I use OpenJDK 1.8, Gradle returns "[!] You need Java 11 or higher to build your app with this version of Gradle.".

If I use Java JDK 20, Gradle returns "BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 64".

Comment: Did you fix this issue